# Using facet_wrap with sliderInput in shiny and order values

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I'm having two problems and maybe they might be separate questions. But since `shiny` has a set of particularities, I've decided to state both problems here.

(I) The first problem is related to using sliderInput function with `facet_grid`. For some reason, the subsetting does not seem to be working within a range but just picking the extreme values of the slider bar.

(I want the plot to show the range and not the values picked in each extreme)

(II) The second problem is related to the ordering of the `Company_Name` variable in my sample data (`sample_data`). I cannot apply a ordering within groups of the `Year`, so that my bar graph is ordered by each year.

(I want the values ordered by each year)

Here it is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


sample_data = data.frame(Company_Name=c("Company 1","Company 2","Company 3",
                                        "Company 1","Company 2","Company 3",
                                        "Company 1","Company 2","Company 3"),
                         Profits_MM = c(20,100,80,
                                        45,120,70,
                                        50,110,130),
                         Sales_MM = c(200,800,520,
                                      300,1000,630,
                                      410,1150,1200),
                         Year=c(2016,2016,2016,
                                2017,2017,2017,
                                2018,2018,2018))


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    # Input(s)
    sidebarPanel(

      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "sel_com",
                         label = "Company Selection:",
                         choices = c("Company 1","Company 2","Company 3"),
                         selected = "Company 1"),


      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Performance Variable",
                  choices = c("Profits (in Millions)" = "Profits_MM", 
                              "Sales (in Millions)" = "Sales_MM"),
                  selected = "Profits_MM"),


      sliderInput("year","Year Selection:",
                  min=2016,
                  max=2018,
                  value=c(2017,2018),
                  step=1)


    ),

    # Output(s)
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "barplot")
    )
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  companies_sel <- reactive({

    req(input$sel_com)

    sample_data_gg = filter(sample_data, Company_Name %in% input$sel_com)
    #  print(sample_data_gg)
    sample_data_gg

  })

  year_sample <- reactive({

    req(input$year)
    sample_data_gg = sample_data
    if(length(input$year)>1){

      Years = seq(input$year[1],input$year[2])

      sample_data_gg = filter(companies_sel(), Year %in% Years)

    }  

    if(length(input$year==1)){

      sample_data_gg = filter(companies_sel(), Year %in% input$year)

    }
    #  print(sample_data_gg)
    sample_data_gg
  })


  output$barplot = renderPlot({

    sample_data_gg = year_sample()

    sample_data_gg = sample_data_gg %>%
                     group_by(Year) %>%
                     mutate(Sigla = factor(Company_Name, 
                                           levels = Company_Name[order(input$y)]))

    y <- input$y
    ggplot(data = sample_data_gg, aes(x=Company_Name, y =get( y ))) +
    geom_col(position="dodge", fill="darkred") +
    facet_grid(Year~., scales = "free_y")  +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) 


  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This question is related to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132817/sliderinput-in-shiny-cannot-set-it-correctly-in-ggplot2-and-update-it)

**Edit**: 
Using the functions posted as answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624394/ggplot-bar-plot-with-facet-dependent-order-of-categories) get the job done for problem II:

```
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}
```

And changing the the rendered plot to:

```
sample_data_gg = year_sample()

y <- input$y
ggplot(data = sample_data_gg, aes(x=reorder_within(Company_Name, get( y ), Year), y = get( y ))) +
  geom_col(position="dodge", fill="darkred") +
  facet_wrap(Year~., scales = "free")  +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is due to your `if` condition because the length of the input is always 1. I would replace it by the following

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

sample_data = data.frame(Company_Name=c("Company 1","Company 2","Company 3",
                                        "Company 1","Company 2","Company 3",
                                        "Company 1","Company 2","Company 3"),
                         Profits_MM = c(20,100,80,
                                        45,120,70,
                                        50,110,130),
                         Sales_MM = c(200,800,520,
                                      300,1000,630,
                                      410,1150,1200),
                         Year=c(2016,2016,2016,
                                2017,2017,2017,
                                2018,2018,2018))


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    # Input(s)
    sidebarPanel(

      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "sel_com",
                         label = "Company Selection:",
                         choices = c("Company 1","Company 2","Company 3"),
                         selected = "Company 1"),


      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Performance Variable",
                  choices = c("Profits (in Millions)" = "Profits_MM", 
                              "Sales (in Millions)" = "Sales_MM"),
                  selected = "Profits_MM"),


      sliderInput("year","Year Selection:",
                  min=2016,
                  max=2018,
                  value=c(2017,2018),
                  step=1)


    ),

    # Output(s)
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "barplot")
    )
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  companies_sel <- reactive({

    req(input$sel_com)

    sample_data_gg = filter(sample_data, Company_Name %in% input$sel_com)
    #  print(sample_data_gg)
    sample_data_gg

  })

  year_sample <- reactive({

    req(input$year)
    sample_data_gg = sample_data
    if((input$year[2] - input$year[1])>1){

      Years = seq(input$year[1],input$year[2])

      sample_data_gg = filter(companies_sel(), Year %in% Years)

    }  

    if((input$year[2] - input$year[1])==1){

      sample_data_gg = filter(companies_sel(), Year %in% input$year)

    }
    #  print(sample_data_gg)
    sample_data_gg
  })


  output$barplot = renderPlot({

    sample_data_gg = year_sample()

    sample_data_gg = sample_data_gg %>%
      group_by(Year) %>%
      mutate(Sigla = factor(Company_Name, 
                            levels = Company_Name[order(input$y)]))

    y <- input$y
    ggplot(data = sample_data_gg, aes(x=Company_Name, y =get( y ))) +
      geom_col(position="dodge", fill="darkred") +
      facet_grid(Year~., scales = "free_y")  +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))


  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I've decided to award you with the answer since you answered the part that was more troubling for me.